# Is "g++ -MMD" better than include scanning?

Tags: gcc, include, dependencies, icc

Whilst looking at build systems, a lot of them (SCons, bjam, cmake, Tundra, etc) have a built-in #include scanner. Yet gcc & icc offer a `-MMD` (or `-MD`) option which outputs the names of the header files that the C++ file depends upon.

The `-MMD` dependency option seems to be reliable. If you add a `#include` to a C file, its timestamp would change so the build system would recompile it. If you add a `#include` to a header file, its timestamp would change and it would recompile all affected C files.

Include scanning systems break, but `-MMD` would seem to me to be robust. Which is best, and why?

Answer (score 17, accepted):

`-MMD` is best, for the reasons you give and more.

Getting the compiler to output dependencies as part of the normal compilation process ensures that the exact same set of compiler options such as `-I` paths and macros are in effect for compilation and when finding dependencies. That's less redundant and less error-prone than ensuring the same options are used for two separate tools.

Comment: Thanks. Do you know why all those tools have #include scanning features then?

Comment: Not everyone uses gcc (or icc), and IIRC older versions of gcc only included filenames in the output of `-MD` not full pathnames, e.g. `foo.o:` instead of `dir1/dir2/foo.o`

Comment: One minor issue of MMD include lists: when you #include <foo.h> it looks through all the -I include dirs. If there are two foo.h files, it reads the first one. Thus, relying upon -MMD will break if you add a new header file with the same name to a -I includedir earlier in the search list.

Comment: That would appear not to be an issue of the `-M` family of options, rather the organisation of the user's project.

Comment: @underscore_d Whose fault it is doesn't matter: it is a pitfall to using `-M` that is worth mentioning here.

Comment: I don't see how it's a pitfall of using `-M` rather than a pitfall of listing prerequisite headers in makefile _at all_. Wouldn't you have exactly the same problem if you listed header prerequisites in the makefile manually? Adding a second `<foo.h>` is likely to break your compilation entirely, and if it doesn't then using `-MMD` doesn't "break" anything, it just means the prerequisite is incorrect until the compiler is run on the source file again.

Comment: A problem with this feature : if your IDE does not keep track of the dependencies, it may lose them when the compiler is not able to compile them again. This is a problem with Netbeans for instance : it deletes the generated dependency file before compilation and cannot retrieve it if the compilation fails.