# How to use makedepend in a non-standard makefile name

Tags: c++, c, makefile, build, dependencies

I am trying to use `makedepend` in a makefile named `Makefile_abc`.
Normally when I have to build a target `trg`, I say

```
make -f Makefile_abc trg
```

and this works beautifully.
I have added following lines in this makefile.

```
dep:
    makedepend  main.c
```

Now, when I do,

```
make -f Makefile_abc  dep
```

I get the error,

```
makedepend: error:  [mM]akefile is not present
make: *** [depend] Error 1
```

If I rename my makefile as Makefile, then following command works fine,

```
make depend
```

So, I am looking for a way to use makedepend on non-standard makefile names.

Answer (score 1):

This is a basic 'read the manual' question.

Looking at [makedepend(1)](https://linux.die.net/man/1/makedepend), you need `-fMakefile_abc` in the recipe for the target `dep` (optionally with a space between `-f` and `Makefile_abc`):

```
dep:
        makedepend -fMakefile_abc main.c
```

To update the dependencies, you'd run:

```
$ make -f Makefile_abc dep
```

This would cause `make` to run:

```
makedepend -fMakefile_abc main.c
```

(Note that the 'standard' — most common — name for the target is `depend` rather than `dep`, so you'd normally run `make -fMakefile_abc depend` or, with a plain `makefile` file, `make depend`.)

If you're using GNU Make, you might also add another line to `Makefile_abc`:

```
.PHONY: dep     # Or depend, depending…
```

This tells `make` that there won't be a file `dep` created by the rule.

You can often get information about how to run a command by using `makedepend --help` or `makedepend -:` — the first may (or may not) give a useful help message outlining options, and the second is very unlikely to be a valid option which should generate a 'usage' message that summarizes the options.

Comment: make -f Makefile_abc  dep -fMakefile_abc,   same result

Comment: The why on earth didn't you mention that you'd tried that?  And are you sure you got the spelling correct?  There was a `Makefile_abc` and a `Makefile_bac` in the question at one time.  What error did you get when you tried that?

Comment: The way you need to use it is when you invoke `makedepend` in the makefile: `makedepend -fMakefile_abc main.c`.  All your command line did is read the makefile twice.

Comment: So, what you are saying is, if I use a standard make file name (Makefile), I can use a target name (dep) in command line.   e.g.,   make dep.      But if I use a non-standard makefile name like Makefile_abc, then I cannot use target name in command line, and I have to use individual source file names in the command line, like main.c.  Is that right.

Comment: @LaeeqKhan there are two different uses of the '-f Makefile_abc' (1) on the make command line to tell make thich makefile to use to find the target dep ; and (2) in the recipe for the dep target to tell makedepend which makefile needs to get the dependencies appended to.

Comment: @ComeRaczy: Thanks for the edit while I was offline.  That's what I intended.

Comment: @ComeRaczy,   Jonathan Leffler, Thanks for help. So the final command line would be,    make -f Makefile_abc  dep -f Makefile_abc   but this does not work, I get the error "[mM]akefile is not present". Do you think, I may be doing something wrong.  Also, do you think we can use the option "-f" twice on the command line? How will make or shell know which file to use for reading target, and which one to use for appending dependencies. Just wondering ...

Comment: @JonathanLeffler: Thanks. Just to clarify for others, there is one "-f" flag that will go inside the Makefile_abc along with makeappend command, and, there is another "-f" flag that will go on the command line indicating the makefile to read. In my case, both these "-f" flags specify the same file "Makefile_abc". Thanks everybody.

Comment: @LaeeqKhan, now that you have figured it out, you should considering an alternative. makedepend has had its use but in some cases it can become a real pain (e.g. when you forget to run `make dep`). with any reasonably recent version of gcc (and other compilers) there is a much better solution: `-MMD -MP`. There are lots of SO posts describing that method, both [how](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/11855386/using-g-with-mmd-in-makefile-to-automatically-generate-dependencies) and [why](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/12106141/is-g-mmd-better-than-include-scanning)

Comment: @ComeRaczy: Thanks, will look at those alternatives. Best Regards